# Connecting Web API to SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

I am fairly new to .net MVC 4 and WEB API. I need to connect my web API to SQL server 2008 but I'm not sure how exactly. I'll I have seen is examples using the local DB and I can't seem to find my solution.

Comment: Does this:- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mds/archive/2010/02/09/getting-started-with-the-web-services-api-in-sql-server-2008-r2-master-data-services.aspx help?

Comment: If you need to be flexible on your data source or want to be able to test the controller actions independently of the data source, consider using a repository pattern. You inject the repository into the controller, and your data manipulation uses the repository abstraction. You are then free to use SQL, In-Memory, Entity Framework, etc. data sources without impacting the controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also want to check out this blog post by Jason Zander.  He includes a very nice step-by-step walkthrough of building a simple Tourist Attraction Application:  [My Favorite Features: Entity Framework Code First and ASP.NET Web API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/23/my-favorite-features-entity-framework-code-first-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

LocalDB is just another engine that is used to access a SQL server database file .mdf -- just like SQLExpress.  Visual Studio 2012 uses LocalDB by default while Visual Studio 2010 uses SQLExpress.  Anyhow, you can just replace the connection string used in the tutorial with your actual database connection string.

Comment: Thanks I ended up just changing the connection string and those are great examples thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial shows how to create a Web API project and connect to a data source using Entity Framework: [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-with-afa30545)

It should give you the gist of what needs to be done.